# How to check if instances of a class with a constexpr constructor get instantiated at compile time?

Tags: c++, constexpr, constexpr-function

How can I check that instances of `MyDouble` will be created at compile time?

What will happen if I instantiate `MyDouble` with a non-constant expression?

```
#include <iostream>

struct MyDouble{
    double myVal;
    constexpr MyDouble(double v): myVal(v){}
    constexpr double getVal(){ return myVal; }
};

int main() {}
```

Comment: What do you think the answer is? Why?

Comment: Please show your attempt

Comment: I'm on a learning journey too.

Comment: Look at `consteval`, `if consteval` and `constexpr MyDouble md1(4.); volatile double x = 3.; constexpr double MyDouble md2(x);`

Answer (score 4):

There is no standard way to determine if a `constexpr` will be evaluated at compile-time or run-time. You can either inspect the assembly, follow the implementation-specific guidelines or try to speculate.

However, using C++20 you can force your existing `constexpr`s to be evaluated at compile-time, or get an error if there is no such possibility. The same logic can act as a test for you.

```
template<class T>
consteval T compile(T exec) 
{
    return exec;
}
```

And then:

```
struct MyDouble
{
    double myVal;
    constexpr MyDouble(double v): myVal(v){}
    constexpr double getVal(){ return myVal; }
};

int main() 
{
    MyDouble x = compile(MyDouble(3.14));
}
```